# Retrieving data/value from elastic search in scala

Tags: scala, elasticsearch

I am new to scala and elasticsearch. I have following data in elasticsearch for index name= "abc" and document type = "_doc".

```
{
  "took": 45,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "abc",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1234",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "Code": "PDF",
          "Description": "Portion Occured",
          "Id": "1234",
          "Operator": {
            "Id": "1",
            "PopulationLevel": "Key"
          },
          "Usage": [
            {
              "Allow": true
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have following code in my elastic search client.

```
trait ElasticsearchClient {

  lazy val esRestConnection: RestClient = createEsRestClient(elasticSearchsUri, elasticSearchProtocol)
  lazy val esHttpConnection: HttpClient = HttpClient.fromRestClient(esRestConnection)

  
   * Method to create instance of HTTP Client to access the given  Elasticsearch URI.
  
   def createEsRestClient(uri: String, protocol: String): RestClient = {
    val hosts = ElasticsearchClientUri(uri).hosts.map {
      case (host, port) =>
        new HttpHost(host, port, protocol)
    }
    RestClient.builder(hosts: _*)
      .build()
  }
}
```

I am using sksamuel elastic4s - Elasticsearch Scala Client

I need to write a code by which I can retrieve value of "Id" i.e 1234 for that particular index. I  have some more index from which I need to retrieve value of "Id" from elastic search. I need to pass index name from my code. How can I do that

Answer (score 0):

```
case class DocumentData(
                       id:Option[Int]
                       )
object DocumentData{
```

implicit val format:Format[DocumentData]=new Format[DocumentData]{

```
override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[DocumentData] = ???

override def writes(o: DocumentData): JsValue = {
  Json.obj(
    "query" -> Json.obj(
      "bool" -> Json.obj(
        "must" -> Json.arr(
          Seq(o.id.map(queryString =>
            Json.obj("match" -> Json.obj(
              "id"->queryString
            ))),
          )
            .flatten[JsObject])))
  )

}
}
}
```